# What are the ranks of monster passive abilities?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

While doing some monster infusion, I had 10 passive abilities on my monster. When I infused again I lost my Pack Mentality passive for Jungle Law. This was completely by mistake (I fail at reading comprehension occasionally). I wasn't paying enough attention to what passives I was infusing.

Some passives have clear ranks, 

example: `Resist Physical +5%   --  Resist Physical +15%`

But others, like Pack Mentality for Jungle Law, don't sound related at all. Was the one that got hacked off random? Or is there a rank system for all passives? If there are ranks for all passives, what are they? I can't seem to find them in game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy guide says that there is a hidden hierarchy for passive abilities.

This answered part of my question. There is a rank system for monster passive abilities, however it is a hidden rank system. I don't want the game deciding which of my abilities is most valuable so I set out to find just exactly what these hidden ranks are. My research led me to a post on [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/61864686) by a user there named laurencium. This user information from a Japanese source and compiled a list of the abilities and their "hidden rank".

Hidden no more!

```
Rank Passive ability
9 Resist Elements: +30%
9 Auto-Haste
9 Auto-Tetradefense
8 HP: +30%
8 Resilience: +40%
8 Auto-Vigilance
8 Ciritical: Haste
8 Critical: Tetradefense
8 Rapid Recovery
7 HP: +25%
7 Strength: +35%
7 Magic: +35%
7 Resist Physical: +36%
7 Resist Magic: +36%
7 Resist Elements: +20%
7 Resilience: +20%
7 Auto-Bravery
7 Auto-Faith
7 Auto-Protect
7 Auto-Shell
7 Auto-Veil
7 Kill: Libra
7 Quick Stagger
7 Role Resonance
6 Strength: +25%
6 Magic: +25%
6 Resist Physical: +26%
6 Resist Magic: +26%
6 Resist Fire: +53%
6 Resist Ice: +53%
6 Resist Deprotect: +66%
6 Resist Deshell: +66%
6 Resist Slow: +66%
6 Resist Poison: +66%
6 Resist Imperil: +66%
6 Resist Curse: +66%
6 Resist Pain: +66%
6 Resist Fog: +66%
6 Resist Dispel: +66%
6 Critical: Vigilance
6 Critical: Power Surge II
6 Critical: Shield II
6 Gilfinder II
6 Item Collector
6 Siphon Boost II
6 Chain Bonus Boost II
6 Stagger Maintenance II
6 Improved Guard II
6 Improved Counter II
6 Augment Maintenance II
6 Improved Debuffing II
6 Improved Debilitation II
6 Improved Cure II
6 Improved Raise II
6 Attack: ATB Charge II
6 First Strike
6 Feral Speed II
6 Ally KO: Power Surge
6 Hindrance
6 Fettered Magic
5 Strength: +20%
5 Magic: +20%
5 Resist Fire: +45%
5 Resist Ice: +45%
5 Resist Lightning: +45%
5 Resist Wind: +45%
5 Resist Elements: +5%
5 Resilience: +10%
5 Critical: Bravery
5 Critical: Faith
5 Critical: Protect
5 Critical: Shell
5 Critical: Veil
5 Critical: Power Surge
5 Critical: Shield
5 Siphon Boost
5 Chain Bonus Boost
5 Stagger Maintenance
5 Improved Guard
5 Improved Ward
5 Improved Counter
5 Augment Maintenance
5 Defense Maintenance
5 Improved Debuffing
5 Improved Debilitation
5 Improved Cure
5 Improved Raise
5 Attack: ATB Charge
5 Kill: ATB Charge
5 ATB Advantage
5 Ally KO: Power Surge
5 Jungle Law
4 HP: +16%
4 Strength: +16%
4 Magic: +16%
4 Resist Deprotect: +44%
4 Resist Deshell: +44%
4 Resist Slow: +44%
4 Resist Poison: +44%
4 Resist Imperil: +44%
4 Resist Curse: +44%
4 Resist Pain: +44%
4 Resist Fog: +44%
4 Resist Dispel: +44%
4 Item Scavenger II
4 Pack Mentality
3 Resist Physical: +15%
3 Resist Magic: +15%
2 Resist Fire: +33%
2 Resist Ice: +33%
2 Resist Lightning: +33%
2 Resist Wind: +33%
1 HP: +10%
1 Strength: +10%
1 Magic: +10%
1 Resist Physical: +5%
1 Resist Magic: +5%
1 Resist Fire: +10%
1 Resist Ice: +10%
1 Resist Lightning: +10%
1 Resist Wind: +10%
1 Resist Deprotect: +10%
1 Resist Deshell: +10%
1 Resist Slow: +10%
1 Resist Poison: +10%
1 Resist Imperil: +10%
1 Resist Curse: +10%
1 Resist Pain: +10%
1 Resist Fog: +10%
1 Resist Dispel: +10%
```

Comment: Thanks laurencium on Gamefaqs for compiling this wonderful information!

Answer (score 0):

When you go over the 10 passive limit, it takes out the most recently added in favor of your new passive(s) according to the in-game tutorials.